# AJAX to start with for MVC4

Tags: ajax

Hi Friends,
                I will be working on a asp.net MVC4 application and As I haven't worked with AJAX in realtime and will have to work soon so I was looking for some article\tutorials\sample to start with. Any suggestion or help on this would be of gr8 help.

Comment: This question isn't really suitable for StackOverflow. Google is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to go if you are going to be jQuery to make asynch calls from your javascript is the jQuery website

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/